PGP with handwritten letters
Alice sends Bob handwritten letters which are all en clair.
In the first letter, she

Includes some private information that makes him sure it's from her
Includes the 40-character fingerprint of her RSA key pair
Tells him to store the letter somewhere safe.

She sends subsequent communications too. These don't include private information. But there is a risk that Carol, an opponent, will try to send fake communications to Bob, presenting them as written by Alice when they aren't. So in every subsequent communication, Alice includes a footnote.
In the nth communication, this footnote

Contains a string $X_n$ of just a few characters, say 5. This can be a real word.

Contains the address $Y_n$ of a webpage that itself contains

her public key, and
the encryption of $X_n$ that she made using her private key


Consists of a line saying nothing more than this: "To verify the authenticity of this letter:

Browse to $Y_n$
Check that the public key on that page has the fingerprint I gave you in my first letter
Using that key, use PGP to decrypt the message that's on that page
Check that it decrypts to $X_n$."



Will this method work?
The idea is that Alice

Can use a different webpage address every time if she wants. (So she doesn't have to depend on any particular web host or website.)
Can think up a new word to encrypt every time, without having to pre-agree a word list with Bob. (So she doesn't have to depend on Bob memorising or otherwise keeping anything other than her first letter. Nor does she herself have to memorise or otherwise keep a list of words, or even a fixed way of generating words.)
Doesn't have to include (in any form) a public cryptographic key in a handwritten letter. (So she doesn't have to depend on having a lot of space on the document to spare, or good enough calligraphic skills to draw a QR code.)

I would be interested to know how Carol might go about defeating this method. We can assume that Bob keeps Alice's first letter in a safe place. We can also assume that Alice has a safe way of getting her subsequent letters to Bob. For example, let's say she puts them through his letterbox. We assume that Carol hasn't got the means to steal a message from his doormat, copy the footnote from it, and replace it with a fake message that contains the same footnote.
